# New to terraform - parsing error while trying to integrate with AWS secrets manager

Tags: terraform, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to integrate with AWS secrets manager using terraform.  I am new to terraform but I have looked at numerous examples online and this seems like it should work but I am getting the error:

```
" error parsing local value "master_username" at 10:21: parse error at 1:113: expected : but found "["[0m[0m".
```

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

```
  master_username = "${local.source_region == "" ? jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.username_password.secret_string)["db.username"] : ""}"
  master_password = "${local.source_region == "" ? jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.username_password.secret_string)["db.password"] : ""}"

data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "username_password" {
  name = "${
    join("/", list(
      "",
      var.stack_env,
      var.service_name
    ))
  }"
}

data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "username_password" {
  secret_id = "${data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.username_password.id}"
}
```

I should note the secrets manager secret exists with the name "/dev/service" and contains key values for db.username and db.password

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:ruby]? Terraform is not a Ruby DSL.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being the version of terraform I was using (0.10.X) and to use decodejson terraform needs to be at least version 0.12.X.  To fix it using an old version of terraform I had to access it using external variables like below

```
data "external" "username_password" {
  program = ["echo", "${replace(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.username_password.secret_string, "\\\"", "\"")}"]
}

  master_username = "${local.source_region == "" ? data.external.username_password.result["db.username"] : ""}"
  master_password = "${local.source_region == "" ? data.external.username_password.result["db.password"] : ""}"
```